# Netlify CMS, Gatsby and GitHub authentication without Netlify

Tags: github, oauth, netlify-cms

Did anyone has luck using OAUTH to authenticate to GB from Netlify CMS but NOT using the Netlify API? If so, what did you use? I want do the authentication with my domain but Im not sure which API or package Should I use for this.
Im learning. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50809299/what-is-the-simplest-way-to-restrict-access-to-a-static-website-using-social-aut/58993785#58993785

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the external OAuth clients are listed under https://www.netlifycms.org/docs/authentication-backends/#github-backend. Currently, there are clients in Node.JS, Python, and Go:

- https://github.com/vencax/netlify-cms-github-oauth-provider
- https://github.com/davidejones/netlify-cms-oauth-provider-python
- https://github.com/igk1972/netlify-cms-oauth-provider-go

Once you set up the server, you can simply add a `base_url` setting point to your OAuth client under your `backend` in your CMS config:

```
backend:
  name: github
  repo: user/repo
  base_url: https://your.server.com # URL to OAuth client
```

Comment: Thank you!
I spent days looking for this simple answer.